# What is an easy way to download all files in a Google Drive to a computer?

Tags: google-drive

I'm in a situation where I have to reinstall OS X on my Mac. Since I don't have an external hard drive, and I don't have that much data (about 40 GB) I'm planning on uploading my files to Google Drive's storage, reinstalling OS X, then downloading those files. Is there an easy way to do this? I searched but the only thing I could find is how to sync a computer to the "cloud" not vice versa.

Comment: [Syncing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_synchronization) is generally two-way. It means your files get uploaded to the cloud, but also stay on your computer.

Comment: Question's half answer: there are tools for uploading like this one: https://driveuploader.com/features/ On the other hand what is wrong with sync? Isn't it easy?

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, just go ahead and Sync: syncing is inherently a two-way street. The files on the cloud will be downloaded to your new computer when connect it to Google Drive.

Comment: So when I log in to Google Drive in the freshly installed OS X, all the files I stored on Google Drive will sync with my computer even if the current Google Drive folder is empty?

Comment: @user90593 yes, that's how cloud backup works.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive sync is not always 100% reliable. I've experienced multiple instances where the synchronization using Google software under Windows or Mac OS X would result in problems. While it never happened that a file would be lost, due to a possibility of problems I would recommend a slightly different approach - assuming there is enough extra space on the local drive.

To be in better control of what is happening with your files consider creating several archives on a local machine, compress them, and transfer them over to the Google Drive. The transfer can be done in a number of ways, from uploading it using Google Drive web interface via a browser, using the Google Drive sync, to using Google Drive API for file transfer - where the upload through the browser is the most viable option in the given scenario. Creating an archive will preserve all information. One large archive is a possibility, however a large file will take longer time to upload and thus increase a chance of upload process breaking. It may be worth trying though as it is more convenient. As per Google's information, files that you upload but don’t convert to a Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides format can be up to 5 TB each.

The file(s) can be downloaded on another machine through the web interface again.

On a Mac running OS X or a similar OS flavor the 'tar' command can be used to both create an archive file and compress it, and on the new machine, to decompress and restore. An alternative is to use a GUI-based archive-and-compression tool.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how this answers the question

Comment: The question was about uploading the files from the existing Mac OS X machine to Google Drive and restoring them on a machine with newly installed Mac OS X. This explains on a high level how do to that, and provides some additional information, in lieu of using the Google Drive sync utility. I believe it does answer the question that was asked; please reconsider your vote - thank you.

Comment: I cannot reconsider a vote that didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

In the web version of Google drive there is a box you can check to select all items in your drive. 
[image]
Then you can download all of those files using the "more" menu:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/takeout) and select Google Drive. You'll be able to download all your files in one go on any other computer.